# Move EIP from EC2 classic to EC2 VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, eip

I've a infra hosting around 300 websites on single EIP. I'm making alot of infrastructure changes and would enforce me to move VPC as classic is deprecated. So is there a way to retain the same EIP (launched in classic)  and associate it with instance in VPC? Problem is i can't update DNS for 300 websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not currently possible to take an elastic ip from classic and use it in a VPC.

[image]

from here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html